# Bootstrap upload issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching for an answer for a couple of days now and i don't understand why am i getting an awful Bootstrap page, using an example from bootstrap.

I uploaded the [same page](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/), .css and .js on github and tried to make it have the same behavior (changed links to js and css).
All the code I have have been taken from the source of the page.
I'm also wondering if it's just me or if you guys have a [totaly weird display](http://jelkya.github.io/index.html).

Comment: Worked on localhost.
Commiting it asap, the 10 min github delay is frustrating me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your developer console, looks like you didn't upload some resources the page depends on:

[image]

```
http://jelkya.github.io/carousel.css
http://jelkya.github.io/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
http://jelkya.github.io/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
http://jelkya.github.io/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular
```

In the particular page you linked, it seems like `carousel.css` may be your culprit.